# What is the difference between JavaFX scripting and Using Regular java Syntax while programming JavaFX Applications

Tags: javafx

I am looking for a detail explanation to the following question.

Can I use regular java syntax to develop JavaFX application? And if so why is the JavaFX scripting so important?

Comment: You do not realy need to write your FX Apps with JavaFX Scripts, you can also use regular Java Code to create your App. Have you read the Oracle Docs already? There are many information about JavaFX and how to use it

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX Script was a language developed for JavaFX 1.x.  [It was dropped for JavaFX 2.x and is no longer supported or developed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#8).

> Can I use regular java syntax to develop JavaFX application?

Yes. All of the JavaFX 2.x system is accessible through regular Java language code running on a Java Virtual Machine. Here is a [sample JavaFX program](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/Login.java.html). You will notice it is just a Java application that provides a [simple GUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/form.htm).

> And if so why is the JavaFX scripting so important?

Students studying the history of computer languages might be interested in the design of JavaFX Script's innovative binding features and declarative programming support.  From a practical development point of view, JavaFX Script is completely obsolete and never used.

---

In addition to the standard [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/), many alternate languages, such as Ruby, Closure, Scala, JavaScript and Groovy are also able to access and use JavaFX.  For scripting JavaFX applications, languages like JavaScript and Groovy take the place of the JavaFX Script language.  An XML based markup called FXML replaces JavaFX Script for declarative definition of GUI scenes.

It's probably a good idea to [review the JavaFX documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/index.html) in detail before asking further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also where can I find some good books using the regular syntax for javaFX or is it just a self taught thing